# How can I create a model of a pnuematic dancer with OpenModelica?

Tags: openmodelica

I've never used Modelica so I'm in difficult for building a model as follows.
I want to create a model in order to simulate the behavior of a pneumatic dancer of a winding machine. There is a spindle that turns and rolls around itself an amount of paper web. The behavior of dancer changes according to the request of paper web. I have a table with data of request based on spindle's angle of rotation.
I'd like to understand how can I build a simple model where a spindle turns at the specific speed (derived by trapezoidal signal -->Modelica.Blocks.Sources.Trapezoid where I've given all parameters of time). I don't want to consider mass and inertia of the spindle. I consider that the spindle is a speed source for the system. So, I have to integrate ( Modelica.Blocks.Continuous.Integrator ) speed in order to obtain the position of the spindle. I have a combiTable1D ( Modelica.Blocks.Tables.CombiTable1D ) with all data request - spindle's angle of rotation. In my model spindle's angle of rotation is named "angolo" and it's the first column in combiTable. 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cAIGe.jpg)

The first question is : Did I choose right blocks for starting my model in this first step?
CombiTable output is the request of paper web based on spindle's position. This output will be the input of dancer system that I'll build in the second step.
I connected this three blocks and I started simulation but I got a translation error. See the follow image. The second question is : Why is there this error? And how can I solve it?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zkg0N.jpg)

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

1) This part is not so clear to me but let me try to answer. You want to generate the angle of rotation of the spindle, I think you mean the angular position of the spindle. For that, what you have done is valid. Just to examplify to give you better insight, you can do that also by writing following lines:

```
  Modelica.SIunits.Angular Velocity angular_speed          "speed of the spindle";
  Modelica.SIunits.Angle angular_position                  "angular position of the spindle";
  parameter Modelica.SIunits.Angle initial_position        "starting angle of the spindle";

initial equation
  angular_position = initial_position;

equation
  angular_speed = trapezoid1.y;
  der(angular_position) = angular_speed;
```

2) You need to define variable "angolo" before using it in your model. You can add something like. Or you can choose a type with a correct SI unit for your variable.

```
  Real angolo "This is where you define your variable";

equation
  angolo = CombiTable1D1.y[1];
```

In general, what I understand is that you already have the angular position of the spindle as a data array and you want to import it into Modelica to used later on. I don't understand why you try to integrate a speed signal generated in Modelica when you already have what you want to achieve in the end.

I think you can benefit very well from Michael Tiller's book [Modelica by Example](http://book.xogeny.com/). [In this example](http://book.xogeny.com/behavior/equations/mechanical/), there are similar initializations you can have look at.